# How to sort elasticsearch resultset on the basis of field preference

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a requirement in which I have to sort elastic search data on the basis of fields.
For Example, I have some docs indexed in elastic search as shown below.

| firstName | lastName | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lily | Sam | someaddress |
| Sam | Adams | anotheraddress |
| Michael | Stevens | SamsoniteStreet |

Sort preference should follow the order from higher to lower
firstName > lastName > address (firstName has the highest preference and address has the lowest)

So If I search "Sam", results should be returned sorted in this order:

| firstName | lastName | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Sam** | Adams | anotheraddress |
| Lily | **Sam** | someaddress |
| Michael | Stevens | **Sam**soniteStreet |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your use case by boosting per field in the [`multi_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html). Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "firstName": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "sam",
      "fields": [
        "firstName^10",
        "lastName^5",
        "address"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 9.808291,
        "_source": {
          "firstName": "Sam",            // note this
          "lastName": "Adams",
          "address": "anotheraddress"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 4.9041457,
        "_source": {
          "firstName": "Lily", 
          "lastName": "Sam",              // note this
          "address": "someaddress"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.8588939,
        "_source": {
          "firstName": "Michael",
          "lastName": "Stevens",
          "address": "SamsoniteStreet"        // note this
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and sorry for the delay in my response. I verified the solution and it works fine. I have one query also If I use "ngram" filter instead of "edge_ngram" than Lily Sam came of first position and Sam Adams on second. Any reason for this? Thank you so much.

Comment: @kumarabhishek I tested the above query for ngrams also, I am getting the same result as shown above, can you please share what index mapping are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I played with boost a bit and got desired results. Thank you so much once again.